# Input numbers in C++ with postfix notation

Tags: c++, input, numbers, postfix-notation

How do I input numbers like 100k or 30M or 41.2G using C++? Is there a library function for that? Or should I write a parser myself?

EDIT:
I figured out a solution myself:

```
static float my_strtod(const char *str)
{
    char *pEnd;
    double val = strtod(str, &pEnd);
    switch (*pEnd)
    {
        case 'k' : val *= 1.0e3; break;
        case 'M' : val *= 1.0e6; break;
        case 'G' : val *= 1.0e9; break;
    }
    return val;
} // end of my_strtod
```

Comment: Those examples don't explain what your format actually is. But even without knowing exactly what you want, there is nothing in the Standard Library (although since 2011, [`regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) may help).

Comment: no, standard conforming c++ compilers are not going to accept that

Comment: I don't know if there are any parser, but writing a parser for this is not difficult

Comment: `41.2G` doesn't particularly look like a number to me. How do you define what a number looks like? You should be more explicit in your definition - give us some set of rules.

Comment: Asking for a library unfortunately doesn't conform to StackOverflow guidelines. If you have some specific problem regarding code you've written for the parser, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Is there any language that has smth like that?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use C++11's `operator""`, something like this:

```
constexpr long operator"" k(long d) {
     return d * 1000;
}
```

then you can create constants like:

```
long distance = 100k;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want a library for that? How about defining stuff this way yourself:

```
typedef double T;
T k = 1e3;
T M = 1e6;
T G = 1e9;
T m = 1e-3;
T u = 1e-6;
```

And then just use them as multiplicands?

Probably those names aren't directly the best; you could find a better convention that wouldn't conflict with anything in your program.